# How to calculate frequency with the voltage received from a vibration sensor?

Tags: sensors

I have been working on a project recently and I am using Sensor **SPM SLD 723**
to read variations in vibrations.

The output I received from the sensor is only in volts, how can I convert this voltage into Frequency (Hz)?

Edit : Actual data received from Device

[image: list of deterioating volts from the device (from 0.16V to 0.14V)]

Comment: It might help some people with their answers if you can provide some more information on the frequency you're expecting (and the magnitude) as well as your environment for processing the data.

Comment: Sure, i will provide actual device data asap.

Comment: From [spminstrument.com](http://www.spminstrument.com/Measuring-techniques/Vibration-monitoring/Vibration-measurement-and-analysis/), it looks like you have to be measuring in a *selected* frequency range.  Is it possible that frequency is the **input**, and voltage would be the **output**, measuring not so much the frequency of vibrations as the amplitude of those vibrations?  I'm not sure, it's the first I've heard of the device: I'm just wondering if this is a possibility.

Comment: I can't see how this is an IoT question. You would probably get better help at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/Althoguh, personally, I would approach the manufacturer and/or their forum first.

Comment: Ok, i will checkout for time variation.. but how can we get the frequency if we have the time variation?

Comment: You still haven't quantified the result you are hoping to observe. All we can guess so far is that the signal/noise ratio is small. You could look at the maths of a fourrier transform and see if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Key here is the datasheet as linked in [Jimmy Westberg's answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/1068/54). The sensor will output:

> The  4-20  mA  vibration   transmitters  are  piezo-electric  accelerometers  of  compression  type   and provide  a   4-20 mA output  signal  proportional to the true RMS value of vibration velocity.

So the output of this sensor is a **current** signal between 4 mA and 20 mA (**not** a voltage) that is proportional to the RMS value of vibration velocity. To read this sensors output the current will have to be converted to a voltage using a [transimpedance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier) (current-to-voltage converter) or measuring the voltage drop acros a well defined series resistor.

However as the sensor output is the [true RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) value of vibrations in the specified frequency range (2..10,000 Hz) it is not possible to obtain the frequency (or to be more precise the wide frequency band) of the vibration with this sensor. To detect the frequency spectrum a measurement of the time waveform of the vibration amplitudes would be necessary.

This [booklet about vibration measurement](https://www.bksv.com/media/doc/br0094.pdf) gives some more insight.

The RMS value is typically used in quantifying the vibration level:

> The    RMS   value   is   the   most   relevant   measure   of   amplitude   because   it   both   takes   the   time   history   of   the   wave   into   account   and   gives   an   amplitude   value   which   is   directly    related    to    the    energy    content,    and    therefore    the destructive abilities of  the vibration.

The purpose of this sensor seems to be for monitoring of machinery where the actual time waveform of the vibration is of little interest. A single value (the RMS value) is sufficient to monitor the operation of the machine against a threshold value. It significantly simplifies measurement.

> Experience   has   shown   that   the   overall   RMS   value   of   vibration   velocity   measured   over   the   range   10   to   1000   Hz gives   the   best   indication   of   a   vibration's   severity.   A probable    explanation    is    that    a    given    velocity    level    corresponds   to   a   given   energy   level   so   that   vibration   at   low and   high   frequencies   are   equally   weighted   from   a vibration    energy    point    of    view.    In    practice    many    machines   have a reasonably flat velocity spectrum.

Answer (score 4):

This is not really an answer to your question but I do find it sometimes hard to understand why you want the real data presented. Take my [light](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Light-Sensor-with-analog-digital-outs/32571120284.html) and [sound](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3pin-Voice-Sound-Detection-Sensor-Module-for-Arduino-DIY-Intelligent-Smart-Vehicle-Robot-Helicopter-Airplane-Aeroplane/32465887653.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.8mmmYC) sensors that I use. They are both analog and thus give me an signal between (in my case) 1V (low) and 3.3V (high). For the light 1V = to a dark room and 3.3V = daylight or direct lamp light. I could go all the way to try to convert these figures to Lux but it doesn't really make any difference since all I want is to know the relative level of light (or sound). So in my case I instead use % for these analog signals. 0% at 1V and 100% at 3.3V.

You might want to consider trying that in your case as well?

**But**, if you do want to try to go all the way you might want to take a look in the [data sheet](http://www.vibrasyon.com/pdf/TitresimSensorleri/TD205B.pdf). The output signal is 4-20mA and they give you that this correspond to 2-1000Hz.